# Setting IIS7 Site Session State to State Server with MSbuild Extension Pack

Tags: iis-7, msbuild, wmi, msbuildextensionpack

Is there any way to choose the Session State Mode to be "State Server" when using MSBuild Extension Pack? I browsed the source code but there is no reference to state management.

Also, if anyone knows how to do this with the Extension Pack WMI that would be great too. I tried all kinds of queries and methods but couldn't come up with a way of talking to IIS through WMI to set SessionStateSection.Mode property "StateServer" flag as stated in MSDN.

Thanks...!

Comment: Take a look : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732412%28WS.10%29.aspx, basically yiou can do it using command line or IIS WMI, is it acceptable for you?